# Switch-to-counter-input

Tags: circuit-design, switches

I’m on my first year of college and learned of flip flops and counters.
I thought that I can make counters from inductive proximity sensor switch.

My first question is can I make input of counter from proximity sensor?

[image]

And can I make the circuit like this? I put opamp to make input higher.
I put AND to check when the counter counts 10th.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- SW1 shorts out the 5V power supply when in position 2
- LM358 output is shorted to ground and inverting input is connected to
  ground through 1kΩ||1kΩ
- LM358 will never switch anyway because input is open or 5V.
- Power supply on LM358 is reversed
- 7490 clock should have much faster tr/tf than an LM358 can deliver,
  <15ns/V, whereas the LM358 slews at 2000ns/V, more than two orders of
  magnitude too slow. This spec is poorly documented for 74xx TTL.
- 7490 clocks are connected unconventionally (usually the /2 drives the
  /5) but I don't think it matters, it will still set the AND gate out
  high at 9. There's no reset provided so it will power up in some
  unknown state, of course.

.. there may be other issues..

You may be able to use a commercial proximity sensor (say an inductive type) directly with a 7490 TTL input, perhaps with a pull-up resistor. If you must have input signal conditioning you would best use a comparator that can drive a legacy TTL input rather than an op-amp.

And if you do use a comparator with hysteresis as you appear to be attempting, you need to establish sensible levels for the two switching points. If I guess what you intended the switching point with comparator output low is poorly defined near 0V, and the input may not satisfy that requirement with much margin or at all. For example, another resistor to Vcc to establish the lower switching point at (say) 2V and the upper at (say) 3V.

As to the maximum clock input rise/fall times, you should always assume there is such a requirement unless there are Schmitt trigger inputs.